# Jquery UI css not loading in ascx WebUserControl

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui, ascx

I'm trying to include a datepicker in one of my WebUserControl. The javascript works fine, however I can't manage to load the css.

I have my css files organized as follow :

[image]

My scripts and stylesheet are called as follow :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script src ="js/datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css, the images are loaded as follow :

```
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #fcefa1;
    background: #fbf9ee url(images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #363636;
}
```

The result however is the following :

[image]

intead of :

[image]

As you can see the javascript works as intended but the css won't load. I've checked the applied style with the chrome debug tool and the style is never loaded on the textbox. It worked perfectly fine when I was loading jquery from the Microsoft CDN however I felt it would be more right to have the file on my server.

I'm 100% sure that my images and css files exist in the folder of the project. I've tried to use relative path (with "~") and the property runat="server" on my link but nothing so far have worked. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in you network tab console?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward actually I do, the css file 404 but I dont understand why

Comment: Please provide you error code and description, are the file copied on the server?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward thanks to you and Bhavesh I've worked my problem out. Since my ascx file was in another directory (WUC), I needed to call the css fil with href="../css/etc.".